# Неравномерное изменение значения DOTween Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с тем, что DOTween неравномерно изменяет значение.

Есть такой код:

```
void Start()
{
    DOTween.To(OnUpdate, 0f, 24f, 60f);
}

void OnUpdate(float value) 
{
    Debug.Log(value);
}
```

В течении 60 секунд нужно плавно и равномерно увеличить значение от 0 до 24.
Вот только сначала значение увеличивается быстро, но чем ближе к 24(финальному значению) тем медленнее.

Например через 30 секунд значение будет не 12, а больше(15, допустим), но чем ближе конечному значению, тем медленнее будет его увеличивать, пока не дойдет к финальному значению.

Можно ли как-то исправить? Есть ли другой вариант плавно и равномерно увеличить значение от 0 до 24 за 60 секунд?

P.S: От 0 до 24 за 60 секунд - это пример. Значения и другие могут быть. Главное увеличивать плавно и равномерно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена добавлением `SetEase(Ease.Linear)`:

```
void Start()
{
    DOTween.To(OnUpdate, 0f, 24f, 60f).SetEase(Ease.Linear);
}

void OnUpdate(float value) 
{
    Debug.Log(value);
}
```